# Are search domains from resolv.conf used only for A/AAAA queries?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnsmasq, unbound

Are the user provided search domains from resolv.conf used only for A/AAAA queries ?

Are they used for any other purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

See [`man resolv.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html). The local `domain` (and possibly other domains specified in `search`) gets appended to a hostname in a query every time it's not a FQDN.

Knowing that, you could easily test whether it works for other RR types or not. You could test that with any existing record like `TXT` for DKIM selector etc. Let's assume we have *SSH fingerprint* `SSHFP` record for `someserver.example.com`:

```
nslookup
> set domain=example.com
> set type=SSHFP
> someserver
```

In this example we actually would get an answer for `someserver.example.com SSHFP` (instead of handling `someserver` as a FQDN), demonstrating how **it works on any RR type**.

Please notice that you can only test this with `nslookup` that uses `resolv.conf` as its initial configuration file. The alternative `dig` always treats all queries as FQDN, i.e.

```
dig someserver SSHFP

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;someserver.        IN  SSHFP
```

Comment: Fwiw, `dig` has a `+search` option if you want it to emulate search behaviour (the actual implementation of search is in the OS resolver library, not actually related to what `dig` does as it is a dns client). I suspect `nslookup` also does something similar as it, being a dns client in itself just like `dig`, shouldn't be using the resolver library.

Comment: Because `nslookup` takes its initial configuration from the same `resolv.conf` than the resolver library, it works for this test (that answers the question) out-of-the-box. Thanks for the addition, though, Håkan!

Comment: I'm not sure this actually proves how the resolver library (and thus regular applications) makes use of the `resolv.conf` settings, though?

Comment: True that! I changed the verb to be a bit more precise.

Comment: I have observed that Windows DNS server does not append the domain name of *nix client's domain mentioned in the resolv.conf file. If I point , in nslookup, to my wifi router then nslookup does append the domain name. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is the OS resolver library which implements the actual *search* functionality, meaning it's use depends on which OS (or other) libraries are actually in use, and nameserver software does not need to know about it at all.

Ie, when an application looks up a name, calling the standard `getaddrinfo`, `gethostbyname` (deprecated), etc functions, the resolver library will make separate lookups for different variations of the specified name as needed.

Now, `getaddrinfo` and `gethostbyname` (when these actually end up using  DNS at all, the resolver library may be configured to use other sources) specifically looks up address records (`A` / `AAAA`), so the question boils down to whether other resolver library code also uses *search* or if its use is limited to these rather narrow purpose functions.

As there are lots of variables (ie, what DNS lookup functionality is a given application actually using?) the short answer to the question is "it depends".

Having a quick look at other functions provided in the oldschool libc resolv library, an application which uses the `res_query` / `res_nquery` functions will NOT search, while an application which uses `res_search` / `res_nsearch` will search.